# Disabling the "Non-code usages" in PHPStorm "Find usages"

Tags: phpstorm

I'm using the great *Find Usages* feature in PHPStorm on a daily basis, and search results fall under one of these two categories:

- Non-code usages
- Found usages

I'm almost never interested in the *non-code* usages. Furthermore, when I'm looking for usages of a method called `get()` or `set()`, it becomes painfully slow as the *non-code* usages show thousands of results.

Is it possible to disable the *non-code* usages, and only return actual *code* usages?

Comment: `Edit | Find | Find Usage Settings` -- try unchecking "Search for text occurrences" option there.

Comment: This only works when you put the cursor on a method/property first, but surprisingly the setting is remembered when you right-click => Find Usages anywhere in the code afterwards! Can you add this as an answer?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Click on a function name

[image: Click on a function name]

---

Go to `Edit`, `Find`, `Find Usages Settings...`

[image: Edit | Find | Find Usage Settings]

---

Uncheck `Search for text occurrences`, and click `Find`

[image: Uncheck Search for text occurrences]

---

While this is not really a global setting, the setting is remembered after the search, and the next time you'll right click to `Find Usages` it will be off by default.

Credits to [LazyOne](https://stackoverflow.com/users/783119/lazyone) for the answer.

Comment: Is there a way to make this persist between restarts of the IDE?

Comment: @Jesse I'm wondering the same thing, it is a big pain! It doesn't even persist between two *find usages* calls for me...

Comment: please vote for the issue (PyCharm) to jetbrains: https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/PY-12627

Comment: I'm using PHPStorm. I cannot achieve that behaviour.

When I place my text caret on class name, and choose Find usages (from menu, from keyboard shortcut, wherever), PHPStorm is searching, but not finding all occurences. When I'm using Linux AG tool (for searchin recursively in directory) Usages are found.

I've tried invalidating cache. Without success.

I've tried with search for txt occurences on and off. No luck. PHPStorm is not finding all usages.

Comment: @mram You should ask your own question if you're looking for answers!